# How do I setup JSS in a TS/NextJS project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I am trying to setup a basic web app using React, TypeScript, NextJS and Material-UI. The issue I am experiencing is with setting styles within the project I have. I've set up a [CodeSandbox environment](https://codesandbox.io/s/2px9q2zkxr) that illustrates my issue.

It's not able to inject the `classes.list` property on line 77 in `Header.tsx`

I've based my code mainly on [this example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/create-react-app-with-typescript) that uses a `withStyles` HOC and have also looked at [this page](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles)  of the MaterialUI docs. However, it still yields the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

The error can also be seen on the CodeSandbox linked above. I am not sure if the error is due to some peculiar thing with how NextJs works as it seems the TS example from the MaterialUI repository works fine. Has anyone done something similar? Or am I trying to do this in a completely unorthodox way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong export that's why.
Change this:

```
export { Header } from "./Header/Header";
```

To this:

```
import Header from "./Header/Header";

export { Header };
```

[Sandbox modified version](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3j08vvxk4)

By the way, next time don't be so complex about naming, (Index, index thing). If you're using Nextjs, just follow their example, don't create another `pages` directory in `components` directory.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also explain why this is causing the error? Or point to some article that explains it? In my mind those two statements should work the same. Also, yes I know the pages in components are a bit too much and I'll clean it up.

Comment: I just noticed that after I apply the fix in your comment, it works fine but after I refresh the page all other CSS disappears from the page. Any clues about that?

Comment: This could be potentially an issue with `material-ui`, I like material design but this package is not wholesome imho.

Comment: What would be a better alternative in your opinion?

Comment: Try this one out: https://mdbootstrap.com. Figure it out for yourself, from my first impression, it looks better.